# How to setup droptable via liquibase?

Tags: java, sql, yaml, liquibase

I want the entire schema to be deleted from the database, yaml + liquibase format.
With the condition that if it does not find any table, then it does nothing and moves on. (Displays a message)

How to set such a condition? At the moment, it gives an error that such a table cannot be found. (When it is deleted)

Options through a repository and sql a script I know. But I started doing this (creating tables and insert) and I would like to do everything in the same style.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UymH6.png)

Comment: Please add the code in the image using the code tags. TY https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Once you've reformatted and posted the error and code as text, I will dig in deeper, but in the meantime, here's a link to the documentation for drop-table: https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/drop-table.html - Also, if you haven't already, you should consider taking the free Liquibase University courses as they'll help provide a lot of the base knowledge to troubleshoot things. https://learn.liquibase.com/catalog

Comment: My teacher said that it is impossible. 
Thank you for links, will check and learn=)